# aspx page that listen to an event

Tags: asp.net

I am seeking a logic to implement a display screen which displays some information when another page postback occures.

To be more precise I have a token queue management system in which the counter officer process a token (in token.aspx page) and when that happens the display screen (display.aspx) should highlight that token.

Which will be the most efficient mechanism to achieve this

**Edit -using SignalR**

My Startup class in App_Code

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup1))]

public class Startup1
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

My Hub class in App_Code

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

public class MyHub1 : Hub
{
    public void Send( string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage( message);
    }
}
```

Now my page for sending data (send.aspx) to hub

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" ></script>  
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>  
  <script>  
        $(function () {  
            var chat = $.connection.myHub1;

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {  
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {  //sendmessage is a button
                    chat.server.send( $('#message').val());  //message is a text field

                });  
            });  
        });  

    </script>
```

No my Display.aspx page

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" ></script>    
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/signalr/
  <script>  
        $(function () {  
            var chat = $.connection.myHub1;
            chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (message) {
                alert(message); 
            };  

        });  

    </script>
```

I have tested and verified that Send.aspx page do send the message to Hub and it is well received. But the Display.aspx page doesnt show the alert.

**Edit 2**

I got it. Actually i forgot to add   $.connection.hub.start(); in Display.aspx page. Now all ok

Comment: Do you mean that when a user currently has a page open, and something happens on the back-end server unrelated to that page, the user's currently open page needs to receive a notification of some kind?  If that's the case then "web sockets" is likely the technology you're looking for, in which the server can "push" information to the client.  Failing that, the page could also have JavaScript code which periodically polls a server endpoint for updated information.  Less efficient, but generally works for reasonable polling intervals.

Comment: @David Yes it is. The page display.aspx will be displayed on a TV screen in a common area. whenever the counter officer process the token (lets say a button click in Token.aspx page) then the display.aspx page should highlight or call that token (invoke a method of Display.aspx page)

Comment: Further to David's comment, SignalR is the standard ASP.NET implementation of the websocket technology. That's likely to be a good choice for your scenario.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you. I was in search of implementing this in my project but was unsuccessful. I am not getting any example to have such option. I will post sample code in my edit. could you please help

Comment: It looks like you managed to make it work, which is great. But if you found the solution you should place it in the Answers section, below, then people can vote on it, and it will show in search results for others who may have a similar question. The solution is not part of the original problem! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SignalR

My Startup class in App_Code

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
.........

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup1))]

public class Startup1
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

My Hub class in App_Code

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
...............

public class MyHub1 : Hub
{
    public void Send( string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage( message);
    }
}
```

Now my page for sending data (send.aspx) to hub

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" ></script>  
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>  
  <script>  
        $(function () {  
            var chat = $.connection.myHub1;

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {  
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {  //sendmessage is a button
                    chat.server.send( $('#message').val());  //message is a text field

                });  
            });  
        });  

    </script>
```

Now my Display.aspx page

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" ></script>    
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/signalr/
  <script>  
        $(function () {  
            var chat = $.connection.myHub1;
            chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (message) {
                alert(message); 
            };  
$.connection.hub.start();
        });  

    </script>
```